# How to use MiniNova USB MIDI keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard

The Novation MiniNova USB MIDI keyboard doesn't work on my setup. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

There are halfway solutions floating on the internet, and perhaps the best suggestion is another query on AskUbuntu (2019), which suggests editing the kernel to get the MiniNova to work properly.

I am open to suggestions. I contacted the keyboard manufacturer but was unable to find a resolution.

Comment: Is [this](https://downloads.novationmusic.com/novation/synthesisers/mininova) the device you are trying to use? The manufacturer doesn't look like they have any drivers for Linux. If the manufacturer doesn't support the device on Linux, you may not be able to use it on Linux. There a [GitHub project](https://github.com/hansfbaier/ultranova4linux/) that is for a different model and claims that it may work on your device. But it also says it has no testing and no support. Without an open source driver from the manufacturer, your only hope is some very determined people to reverse engineer one.

Comment: You can get a little more info by watching the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in your MIDIkeyboard.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Waltinator: that didn't work.